# Combination of macros and template in generating Object

Tags: c++, qt, templates, c++11, macros

I create a template class for filling some objects of class T, however objects of T is shared in network and i dont want give so information on them so i create a helper class for every class T and a macro:

```
 class Entity {
     // just Properties
 }
 class EntityHelper{
    // needed method for fill from database
 }

 #define DBH(x) x##Helper
```

and this is a function of context class for filling a list of object

```
 template<class T> 
 QList<T> ContextClass::query(const QString& q){
    T inst;
    DBH(T) helper;
    // and another methods
 }
```

i get THelper undeclared identifier error!!
if i dont use function m->query(q); i dont get error??
i know i can use another way for doing this, but in this approach what is wrong?

**UPDATE:**

ok it seems i must use another approach i used this?

```
template <class T>
class Helper {
    Helper<T>* createInstance();
    //some methods
}

class EntityHelper : public Helper<Entity>
{
     EntityHelper* createInstance();
      // query needed for entity table database
}
```

Comment: `i dont want give so information on them` What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: my entities is just a DTO object and i share this objects with another applications so i dont want keep database information like column names and tables in this objects, a EntityHelper know all about database stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember macros are just text replacements, so your code becomes:

```
 template<class T> 
 QList<T> ContextClass::query(const QString& q){
    T inst;
    THelper helper;
    // and another methods
 }
```

which is nonsense...

In your case, just use template:

```
template<class T>
class Helper;

template<>
class Helper<Entity>
{
    // needed method for fill from database
};

template<class T> 
QList<T> ContextClass::query(const QString& q){
   T inst;
   Helper<T> helper;
   // and another methods
}
```

Comment: i have different class members for every Helper, each helper is static definition i cant use this too, why when i dont use this function i havent any error?

Comment: I do get an error, maybe you can show us more code? Note that you can specialize `Helper` for each `T` so they can have different class members.

Comment: if i add a THelper class just for giving no error, for another T its always use THelper or replace T with class Name, i mean compiler first replace macros next create template functions or not?

Comment: ok it seems i must use your suggestion, but how can i use different derived class of helper

Comment: Why do you want to derive from `Helper<Entity>`? do you know you can specialize `Helper` template? I updated the code to clarify the idea.

Comment: Thank you so much this is what i want , idont know that thanks a lot.